# How to obtain inner html of a link using an id of a surrounding table cell

Tags: html-agility-pack

I've started using the Html Agility Pack and liking it a lot.

I have the following html:

```
<td id="1"><a href="/offIgo.aspx">This Link</a></td>
<td id="2"><a href="/offIgo.aspx" class="">Not This Link</a></td>
```

I would like to obtain the inner html from the anchor when the table cell has an id of 1

i.e. the end result is that I'm left with "This Link"

I've managed to get the inner html when passing in the href:

```
 var doc= new HtmlWeb().Load("mypage);
        var selections = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Where(u => u.GetAttributeValue("href", null).Contains("offIgo"))
            .Select(a => a.InnerHtml);
```

But how would I go about incorporating the table cell information? Is it a case of taking a step back and getting all the information from the  tags first and then drilling further in?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out what to do so for those who come across this, try the following:

```
        var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("myPage");
        HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tbody//tr//td[@id='r1']");
        var myAnchorText = node.Descendants("a")
        .Where(u => u.GetAttributeValue("href", null).Contains("offIgo.aspx"))
        .Select(a => a.InnerHtml);
```